# @DateTimeFormat and TO_DATE() pattern for Calendar type passed through rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm working on Web application which is using Spring Data JPA and Oracle Database. I was using ***@RepositoryRestResource*** annotation in interface where I was just declaring some query methods with named parameters using ***@Param*** and ***@Query*** annotations. Today I needed to add a new entity with the dates. In database one column is type of **DATE** and the other one is type of **TIMESTAMP**. And below the Java representation of this two columns only, of course with all setters and getters, but it has more fields so just adding this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "INIT_DATE")
private Calendar initDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "AGG_DATE")
private Calendar aggDate;
```

I also created new interface for case, the same way as always:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "customer", path = "customer")
public interface ICustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c where c.initDate <= TO_DATE(:currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND c.aggDate >= TO_DATE(:currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')")
    public List<Customer> filterByDate(@Param("currentDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Calendar currentDate);

}
```

I also tried other format, but I'm receiving this error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

I'm trying to get this data from database using this http request:

```
http://localhost/webApp/customer/search/filterByDate?currentDate=2017-07-10
```

And to be honest, I have no idea what is the problem here... The format date in the database is yy/MM/DD, but it also wasn't working for me... Could you tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong??

Comment: Is the query string run on a DB console w/o error? You should consider the format string as given below http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: As I remember it was working fine. Unfortunately I cannot check this right now. But the format string seems to be correct for me. So I don't know what is the problem...

Comment: JPQL has no such function `TO_DATE`.

Comment: @NeilStockton so what I should do in this case??

Comment: You want `date <= :paramDate`, and ?

Comment: @NeilStockton I also tried this, but than its not returning anything when it should!

Comment: and what SQL is actually invoked? aka debugging